# How to convert a DB5 database into Mongo DB?

Tags: mongodb

Is there a simple way to convert a DB5 file that I can open in excel and some how convert that into a MongoDB structure?

Answer (score 2):

Since you can open in in Excel, export/save/convert/... it as CSV and import in in Mongo using [mongoimport](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-mongoimport). Haven't done it myself but it seems like a valid choice to use mongoimport if you don't mind the conversion to CSV.